# React Native, redux function not going to original state after updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a function to view cart details below every screen when a user add a item to cart and when user remove function cart details will hide again, but when I remove item from cart, cart details not hidding, can someone tell me what's wrong, below is my code

reducer

```
 if (action.type === SHOW_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.addedItems;
    if (addedItem === 0) {
      console.log(addedItem);
      return {
        ...state,
        show: state.showCart,
      };
    } 
  } 


const initialstate = {
  showChart: false,
  addedItems: [],
}
```

It's my redux code where I'm performing that function, addItems is my cart which is blank array

action

```
export const showCart = (id) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_CART,
    showCart: true,
    id,
  };
};
```

Here is my action

ViewCart

```
  {this.props.show ? (
          <View style={styles.total}>
            <Text style={styles.totaltext}>Total:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceTotal}>{this.props.total}</Text>
            <View style={styles.onPress}>
              <Text
                style={styles.pressText}
                onPress={() => RootNavigation.navigate("Cart")}
              >
                View Cart
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : null}
```

Here is my view cart detail where I showing cart details when user add item to cart
can someone please help

Comment: the question is kind of unclear. where are you "removing" an item from the cart?

Comment: in cart component should i add it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the length, you are currently comparing the array directly so it would also go to the false path, so change that first.

```
if (action.type === SHOW_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.addedItems;
    if (addedItem.length === 0) {
      console.log(addedItem);
      return {
        ...state,
        show: state.showCart,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        show: action.showCart,
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you see the console.log ?

Comment: yup function is making condition true when i add item but didn't make it false on remove

Comment: show: state.showCart should be show: state.show change that as well

Comment: didn't worked :/ and why it should state.show, in initial state it's showCart

Comment: to make condition false,  It's done. just need to add this.props.itmes.length > 0 in View cart, now i need to remove the from cart component  my sir said do it by dispatching function Iscart = true, now i need to figure out how to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223167/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-kanwarjeet-singh).

Answer (score 0):

In view cart,

```
 {this.props.show && this.props.items.length >0 ? (
          <View style={styles.total}>
            <Text style={styles.totaltext}>Total:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceTotal}>{this.props.total}</Text>
            <View style={styles.onPress}>
              <Text
                style={styles.pressText}
                onPress={() => RootNavigation.navigate("Cart")}
              >
                View Cart
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : null}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    total: state.clothes.total,
    show: state.clothes.show,
    items: state.clothes.addedItems,
  };
};
```